# pdf page fliping

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf

I want to flip the pdf pages on iphone.  I load the pdf file on iphone but it is scrolling I want to flip pdf pages... please give me any helo

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a view or a layer for every pdf page. You do so by creating a UIView subclass and inside drawRect: use the CGPDF* functions to extract and render a given page of your pdf.

You could then use UIViewTransitons or CoreAnimation to animate the pages of your PDF.

See:

- [Chapter PDF Document Creation, Viewing, and Transforming of Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101)
- [Chapter Modifying Views at Runtime of View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW35)